# Solutions in Javascript to deal with arrays and averages with daisy-chain ternary?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I am trying to understand arrays and functions in JavaScript better and I find it difficult to sort array values and return its equivalent container

I like simple ternary chains than if/else conditions and switch case statements due to lesser code but I want to do away with coding the calculation of averages in arrays and maybe return the names of shooters if they have the highest average or something. I would appreciate functions and if there be mathematical formula that I am missing out. Thanks.

```js
var Steph, RayA, LarryB, AvSteph, AvRay, AvLarry, Ax;

Steph = [286, 402, 324];
RayA = [116, 103, 123];
LarryB = [90, 82, 80];

AvSteph = (Steph[0] + Steph[1] + Steph[2]) / Steph.length;
AvRay = (RayA[0] + RayA[1] + RayA[2]) / RayA.length;
AvLarry = (LarryB[0] + LarryB[1] + LarryB[2]) / LarryB.length;
Ax = [AvSteph, AvRay, AvLarry];

console.log(' Steph\'s average is ' + AvSteph, '\n Ray\'s average is ' + AvRay, '\n Larry\'s average is ' + AvLarry);

Ax[0] > Ax[1] && Ax[0] > Ax[2] ? console.log('Stephen Curry is the 3-point Hero') :
  Ax[1] > Ax[0] && Ax[1] > Ax[2] ? console.log('Ray Allen is the 3-point Hero') :
  Ax[2] > Ax[0] && Ax[2] > Ax[1] ? console.log('Larry Bird is the 3-point Hero') :
  Ax[0] == Ax[1] && Ax[0] == Ax[2] ? console.log('It is a three tie win!') :
  Ax[0] == Ax[1] && Ax[0] > Ax[2] ? console.log('It\'s a tie! Stephen Curry and Ray Allen are the 3-point Heroes') :
  Ax[0] > Ax[1] && Ax[0] == Ax[2] ? console.log('It\'s a tie! Stephen Curry and Larry Bird are the 3-point Heroes') :
  Ax[0] < Ax[1] && Ax[1] == Ax[2] ? console.log('It\'s a tie! Ray Allen and Larry Bird are the 3-point Heros') :
  console.log('I\'m not sure who the 3-point Hero is :( ');
```

This returns:

```
Stephen's average is 337.33 
Ray's average is 114 
Larry's average is 84
Stephen Curry is the 3-point Hero
```

Looking for a lesser and optimal code... Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Ouch. The space bar is your friend. :)

Comment: using ternary operators in this case makes code harder to understant.I haven't.Use old good if statements

Comment: @ManosKounelakis thanks for the prompt reply. I like the good old Ifs too but ternary seems to save me a lot of space. My concern though is with passing values to array and to sort them and then return its parent container to be used in reporting  if there is such thing :( like: RayA=114 in the Ax[...] and return RayA after sorting max

Comment: @ManosKounelakis below is if/else statement kindly check:
    if(Ax[0]>Ax[1]&&Ax[0]>Ax[2]) {
    console.log('Stephen Curry ...');}   else if(Ax[1]>Ax[0]&&Ax[1]>Ax[2]) {
console.log('Ray Allen is ...');
}   else if(Ax[2]>Ax[0]&&Ax[2]>Ax[1]){
console.log('Larry...');
}   else if(Ax[0]==Ax[1]&&Ax[0]==Ax[2]) {
console.log('It is a thr...');}
else if(Ax[0]==Ax[1]&&Ax[0]>Ax[2]) {
console.log('It\'s ...');
}   else if(Ax[0]>Ax[1]&&Ax[0]==Ax[2]) {
console.log('It\'s ...');
}   else if(Ax[0]<Ax[1]&&Ax[1]==Ax[2]) {
console.log('It\'s ...');
}   else { console.log('I\'m not...'); }

Comment: @PaulKurtis please update your question using the code you commented and don't forget to format the code.It is not readable at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use objects to store averages

```js
var Steph, RayA, LarryB, avg;

Steph = [286,402,324];
RayA = [116,103,123];
LarryB = [90,82,80];
avgObj = {}; //to store avg: array of names of people  with that average

['Steph', 'RayA', 'LarryB'].forEach(name=>{
  let avg = this[name].reduce((a,c)=>a+c,0)/this[name].length;
  avgObj[avg] = avgObj[avg] || [];
  avgObj[avg].push(name);
});
console.log({avgObj});


let winner = Math.max(...Object.keys(avgObj));
let winnerName = avgObj[winner];
let str = winnerName.length > 1 ? "Tie between " : "Winner is ";
console.log(str + winnerName.join())
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should define a function to do averages on any array, of any length:

```
function getAverage(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }) / array.length;
}
```

Then create an array with names and averages in it:

```
var averagesByName = [
  {name: 'Stephen Curry', average: getAverage(Steph)},
  {name: 'Ray Allen', average: getAverage(RayA)},
  {name: 'Larry Bird', average: getAverage(LarryB)}
];
```

Then sort this array:

```
// Sort highest first, lowest last
averagesByName.sort(function(a, b) { return b.average - a.average })
```

You'll still need make special checks for ties, but you don't have to do it name by name.

Comment: thanks for this @kshetline... I will need to check this out to understand better...

Answer (score 0):

You could move the data into an object and get the averages and the max value. Then check how many items have the max average.

```js
const
    add = (a, b) => a + b,
    getAverage = array => array.reduce(add, 0) / array.length;

var data = { Steph: { points: [286, 402, 324] }, RayA: { points: [116, 103, 123] }, LarryB: { points: [90, 82, 80] } },
    keys = Object.keys(data),
    avg = {},
    max;
    
keys.forEach(k => {
    data[k].avg = getAverage(data[k].points);
    (avg[data[k].avg] = avg[data[k].avg] || []).push(k);
});

max = data[keys.reduce((a, b) => data[a].avg > data[b].avg ? a : b)].avg;


if (avg[max].length === 3) console.log('triple win');
else if (avg[max].length === 2) console.log('tie with ' + avg[max].join(' and '));
else console.log('winner: ' + avg[max]);

console.log(avg);
console.log(max);
```

Comment: truly appreciate your input here @Nina 
I am trying to understand the code now
thanks